# Question maximum modulus principle/continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

The maximum modulus principle states:

> Suppose that a function f is continuous on a closed bounded region $R$ and that it is analytic and not constant in the interior of $R$. Then the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ on $R$, which is always on the boundary of $R$ and never in the interior.

Could someone explain why on the boundary it suffices for f to be continuous and not analytic?